# Display Push Notification on Screen Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the message from a push notification to display on the screen of the phone not just in the drop down menu of the device.
Right now, I can get the messages to come through from FireBase and alert the user that it has arrived. This works in the foreground and the background. But I would like some kind of counter or alert on the screen to appear. Perhaps in a label or textbox. This is for an Android application but the project is being built in Xamari Forms with PCL.

My token class:

```
 [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] {"com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"})]   
    public class FireBaseTokenRefresh : FirebaseInstanceIdService
    {
        const string TAG = "FireBaseIDService";
         public override void OnTokenRefresh()
         {
             var refreshtoken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
             Log.Debug(TAG,"Refresh Token: " + refreshtoken);

         }

    }
```

My foreground messaging class:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]

public class ForegroundMessages: FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        //Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
        //Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        SendNotification(message.GetNotification().Body);
    }

    private void SendNotification(string body)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + body);

var defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
            .SetContentTitle("Notification")
            .SetContentText(body)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

And some changes to MainActivity:

```
[Activity(Label = "Watson", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // this is registering the services 
            ServiceContainer.Register<IWebService>(() => new WebService());
            ServiceContainer.Register<ISettings>(() => new Settings());

            // This is getting the IMEI number this method is unique to android 
            var telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
            string imei = telephonyManager.DeviceId;

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            Task.Run(() => {
                var instanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
                instanceId.DeleteInstanceId();
                Android.Util.Log.Debug("TAG", "{0} {1}", instanceId.Token, instanceId.GetToken(GetString(Resource.String.gcm_defaultSenderId), Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope));


            });


            LoadApplication(new App(imei));
        }


    }
```

There seem to be plenty of tutorials on this kind of thing but they log out to debug. This is essentially useless for a real application.
How can I get the message to display in a view or on screen? It doesnt even have to be the message it can even just be listener that knows when the message has arrived and alerts the user and gives the user the option to read the message in a pop up or on another screen.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want display a dialog or something when the app receive the push notification?

Comment: Something along those lines. Sorry for the lack of clarity. Because this is PCL and Xamarin Froms I am not sure how to pass the message information up to the Xamarin forms views. Although if there is a native solution for just Android that would be good as well.

Comment: You can use [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) to pass the  message information up to the Xamarin forms views.

Comment: Thanks. I will  take a look at this.

Comment: I did yeah. I use the messaging centre functionality, that is listening in the mainactvity class and sends up to the view model in the PCL. When the message arrives it signals up to the view model and this increments a counter that is tied to an observable collection that updates the front end. 
Let me know if you want me to post the code.

Comment: Just confirm that whether this problem is solved, if not, I want to solve it. Happy coding. : )